# Trying to insert some data into my database through a web app

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name
>   'address'. at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action 1 wrapCloseInAction) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
>   SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
>   RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
>   async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader
>   ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
>   method, TaskCompletionSource 1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
>   Boolean asyncWrite) at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
>   reg.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Urban\Desktop\Gledalisce\reg.aspx.cs:line 51
>   ClientConnectionId:398be50f-0c3e-442f-b15c-343c1971f7db Error
>   Number:207,State:1,Class:16

This is the error I get when trying to submit the regestration form.

This is the part of code I'm using.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegestrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                string insertQuery = "insert into [User] (ID_username,password,name,surname,address,city,post_num,mobile_num,email,dateOFbirth,sex,pickUPcode) values (@username,@password,@name,@surname,@address,@city,@post_num,@mobile_num,@email,@dateOFbirth,@sex,@pickUPcode)";
                SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",username.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", city.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post_num", post_num.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobile_num", mobile_num.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Email.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOFbirth", date_birth.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", sex.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pickUPcode", code.Text);
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Response.Write("Regestracija je uspela!");
                Response.Redirect("admin.aspx");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { Response.Write("Napaka: " + ex.ToString()); }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me!

Comment: `Invalid column name 'address'` - what's not clear about this error?

Comment: Show your database design.   Check  if you are missing any columns

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no column called `address` in your `User` table.